# How to properly consume http service in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I have created the following component and it's a small demo so I am consuming service here instead of creating a separate service.

```
export class AppComponent {    
    @Input() takeInput:string;
    @Output() result;
    constructor( private http: Http) { };

    public onSubmit(value: any){
        this.takeInput = value;

        this.getAll(value.url); //below console.log prints first then the one prints which is written inside this getAll method.

        console.log("this prints first", this.result); //returns undefined
        //How do I use this.result here which gets set once getAll() execution is finished.
    }
```

Here is the method to call service and get data:

```
private getAll (url){
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((res: Object) => {
            this.result = res;
            console.log("this prints second",this.result); // returns proper response
        });
    }
}
```

How can wait for observable to return data and then use that data in my calling method onSubmit() or any other way to continue execution using this.result as a parameter for other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your `getAll` method like this to move out the subscription on the corresponding observable:

```
private getAll (){
  let url = "https://something";
  return this.http.get(url)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public onSubmit(value: any){
  this.takeInput = value.takeInput;
  this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.result = result;
    console.log(this.result);
  });
}
```

Comment: but still asyc code execution continuous and I get this.result = undefined in the next line.

`public onSubmit(value: any){
  this.takeInput = value.takeInput;
  this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(myResult);  //returns data
    console.log(this.result); //returns data
  });
}
public otherMethod(this.result) => {
console.log(this.result) //runs before data is fetched from service and hence undefined
}
`

Comment: Yes sorry! There were typos in my code... I updated my answer.

Comment: could you have a look, I have simplified the question to focus on pain point.